# How to check if field exists in an entity?

Tags: entities

In entity node, I want to check if '`abc`' field exists or not. If exists, I will get its value by `$value->get('abc').`

But the content type where this field doesn't exists, gives error:

**The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.**

How to check if field exists in an entity?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Since Drupal 8, you can use [`FieldableEntityInterface::hasField()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21FieldableEntityInterface.php/function/FieldableEntityInterface%3A%3AhasField).

```php
$entity->hasField('abc')
```