# How to check if an entity bundle has a field?

Tags: 8, entities

How can I check if a bundle has a field? I know I can use `$entity->hasField()` if I have a specific entity (as is defined in [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204669/how-to-check-if-field-exists-in-an-entity)), but how can I get this info with just the entity_type and bundle info?

I'm assuming I could just create an entity of the type and bundle (and never save it), and check against that, but that seems gross.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Woops, this is closely related to [Get all fields defined in a bundle](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161293/get-all-fields-defined-in-a-bundle), but since that gets all fields, I'll post this.

Use the [EntityFieldManager (entity_field.manager)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/class/EntityFieldManager/8.5.x) service, specifically the [getFieldDefinitions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManager.php/function/EntityFieldManager%3A%3AgetFieldDefinitions/8.5.x) method, to get all field definitions, and then check for your specific field.

```
function doesBundleHaveField($entity_type = 'node', $bundle = 'page', $field_name = 'field_paragraphs') {
  $all_bundle_fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions($entity_type, $bundle);
  return isset($all_bundle_fields[$field_name]);
}
```

Comment: an isset($all_bundle_fields[$field_name]) is enough, array_key_exists() is only necessary if your array key might be NULL and you still want to return TRUE. Not the case here

Answer (score 4):

You can use static method loadByName from FieldStorageConfig, which will return field config entity if one exists for the provided field name, otherwise NULL. Then get the attached bundles and filter by your correspondent bundle:

```
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;
$field_storage = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('node', 'field_foo');
if (!empty($field_storage) && in_array('page', $field_storage->getBundles())) {
  // TODO: Implement this.
}
```

Comment: I believe this answer is preferred since not all entity types support the `getFieldDefinitions` method. I was trying this on commerce_product_types and got the error: `"Getting the base fields is not supported for entity type Product type."`